# Add columns dynamically into temp table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i adding data into one temp table from one xml file ..the code is below..

```
SELECT * INTO #TempBusinessUnitFacility FROM OPENXML(@iBusinessUnitFacilityLinkTree, 'BusinessUnits/BusinessUnit', 1)  
    WITH (BU_Facility_LinkClientCode INT 'BU_Facility_LinkClientCode',BU_Code INT 'BU_Code',Facility_Code INT 'Facility_Code')
```

suppose  i got nearly 10 rows and i want to do while loop and insert values from temp table to some other table by row by row.the problem is i don't have identity column or row no here.if i can add row no as a identity column , then i can do my operation easily.how can i add one column as identity in this temp table.

i can create one temp table add columns and insert values into it from xml.but that is not my scenario.is there any option for my above scenario.anybody can sort it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
selet row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as id,
      *
INTO #TempBusinessUnitFacility FROM OPENXML(@iBusinessUnitFacilityLinkTree, 'BusinessUnits/BusinessUnit', 1)  
WITH (BU_Facility_LinkClientCode INT 'BU_Facility_LinkClientCode',BU_Code INT 'BU_Code',Facility_Code INT 'Facility_Code')
```

This uses `row_number()` to assign the id.